# Loading data into BigQuery via Cloud Functions and Google Cloud Storage - Exceeding socket traffic quota limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've got a Google Cloud Function (GCF) that watches Google Cloud Storage (GCS). When a file drops into a particular bucket, the GCF fires up a LoadJob telling Big Query (BQ) to import the file.

I'm using the [NodeJS LoadJob function](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Table#createLoadJob) that (from what I understand) is supposed to just instruct BQ to import the file directly. In other words, BQ is supposed to talk to GCS, rather than my GCF being a middleman and streaming the data in some fashion.

However, when my function runs on a lot of files at once, I get the following GCF quota error:
`Outgoing socket traffic for region us-central1 : per 100 seconds`

The default quota value is `10737418240`, which I assume is in bytes, making the quota ~ 10GB every 100 seconds.

Why should my GCF be making *any* outgoing socket traffic? The only thing I'm doing is setting up a BQ job to import. All of that should be internal, and further, it should all be directly between BQ and GCS, not using my GCF quotas/bandwidth. The files are pretty big, but isn't that exactly the point of loading into BQ directly from GCS?

Note: Upon reading my code a little closer, I'm also doing a query to move data from one BQ table to another. However, similar to the load job, this is a [QueryJob](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/Table#createQueryJob) that specifies a destination table to place the results in it. So, none of that data should be streaming through my GCF, and instead all data transfer should be occurring within BQ.

Comment: I believe this question would be better suited to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

The data transfer actually comes from unzipping a file to GCS. I receive a large .tar.gz containing multiple files, so I unzip (as a stream) to GCS. This is where all the data transfer comes from.

It's a little strange strange to me that this is considered outgoing socket traffic, since it's internal to the Google datacenter.